# Old alien invasion story with character called Grimper or Gramper

Tags: story-identification, alien-invasion

I'm trying to ID an old science fiction story featuring an (older) resistance fighter whose grandchildren tagged him something like *Grimper* or *Gramper*.

He left [Kilroy-style](http://www.kilroywashere.org/01-Images/Kathy/KilroyWasHereMarkerInscription.jpg) graffiti with that name, which terrified the alien invaders.

Comment: Anything else you remember? Ho old is it? What language? What country? Anything particular about the medium (i. e. collection of stories, magazine, etc.) or even the book cover?

Comment: What made this story science fiction?

Comment: @OrganicMarble  -  `[alien-invasion]`?

Comment: Ah. Thanks. Missed that.

Comment: I'm unsure why this has been closed. The details are a bit sparse, but it's gonna be easily identifiable to someone who actually knows this story.

Answer (score 7):

The novel is [Sleeping Planet by William R. Burkett, Jr](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5597).

Alien invaders spray Earth with chemical that puts everybody to sleep, with a couple of exceptions. One captured awake human starts spooking the alien troops by telling horror stories about the vengeful ghost of his dead grandfather. The aliens mispronounced  the name as "gremper".

Meanwhile on the ground a second awake human gets wind of this and starts a psyops campaign pretending to be the dreaded gremper.